# CPU usage of epoll_wait(-1) vs defined timeout?

Tags: linux, epoll

Does epoll_wait(-1) takes more CPU in compare with some defined intervals say 1sec?

Br,
Neeraj

Comment: No, it takes less, because it doesn't wake up.